# Paypal Express Checkout not working

Tags: jquery, html, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to use PayPal Express Checkout, I am not sure if it is working correctly with the sandbox.

[image]

It opens the popup for sanbox use but shows the amount as 20,00 not as 20.00 and after selecting the Credit Card & clicking the  "PayNow" Button. it shows processing icon for few seconds and closes the popup without showing the confirmation message for payment.

Below is the script i am using. I am not sure if its script which i have put in a wrong way or due to the country restriction of Merchan Account in certain countries. This Merchant account is in UAE,

Express Checkout Pay with Paypal

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

        client: {
            sandbox:    'XXXXXXX-zhSadKHA8asdasdasdtuqywqwqohasnaAGauaASadacs',
            production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        },

        payment: function() {

            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;

            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '20', currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Optional: display a confirmation page here

            actions.payment.get();

            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                // Show a success page to the buyer
                console.log(data);
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:

In Sandbox activity it shows transaction are through. This is what it indicate. same script was not working few days back not sure.

So it seems it is working but not showing the confirmation message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a confirmation message, that's up to you. You can use `actions.payment.get().then(function((result) { ... });` to get the buyer's details before confirming, then call `actions.payment.execute()` only when you're ready to complete the payment. Neither of these functions will display a confirmation for you, though.